# Subclipse plugin build error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I'm trying to build a slightly modified version of Subclipse (exporting "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" from Eclipse).

I'm getting an error which stumps me:

F:\MyWorkspaces\Subclipse\org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui\build.xml:163: unbalanced quotes in -log 'F:/MyWorkspaces/Subclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/destination/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.18/@dot.log'

Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Any advice on how to go about figuring out what's wrong?

Both files mentioned (build.xml and @dot.log) don't exist after the error pops up so they must be temp files created at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just creating a local update site project, adding the Subclipse feature to it and then building the update site?  That is how I build Subclipse.